# nvalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: mysql

Got it working somehow no need for answers. Thanks all.

```
function upBook($id)    {   
    $request    =   Slim::getInstance()->request(); 
    $body   =   $request->getBody();    
    $books  =   json_decode($body); 
    $sql    =   "UPDATE books SET 
                book_name=:book_name, 
                book_price=:book_price, 
                WHERE book_id=:id"; 
        try {   
            $db =   getConnection();    
            $stmt   =   $db->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->bindParam("id",  $id);   
            $stmt->bindParam("book_name",   $books->book_name); 
            $books  =   $stmt->fetchObject();   
            $db =   null;   
            responseJson(json_encode($books),200);  
    }   catch(PDOException  $e) {   
}
```

The exception I get in console every time is:

```
{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens}}
```

Comment: So you are getting an exception?

Comment: Did you really mean to do a `$books  =   $stmt->fetchObject();` after an `INSERT` query? If so, what are you expecting to get returned at that point?

Comment: Any `bindParam` call returning false ?

Comment: the problem mentioned by @RiggsFolly will trigger an exception for sure but from what I have seen until now the message usually is "general error".. but maybe there's a difference in driver or version.. so you can still try to 1) check if maybe the update was completed even if you see an error message 2) comment out that line just for a test

Comment: Did you mix up "book_release_date" and "book_date"? EDIT: Nevermind, just noticed the parameter actually *is* called "book_date"...

Comment: Please put all the relevant information in the body of the question. If needed, edit your question and update it.

Comment: Information doesnt get updated even with the error appearing and commenting out the stated line also did nothing. On firebug the information shows that it has been taken in but wont get pushed onto the database.